# How to find all <!--/noindex--> tags using xpath, ruby & webdriver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

xpath = //comment()[contains(.,'noindex')] is working for me in Selenium IDE, but it won't work using ruby & webdriver.
How to find all  tags?
I'm trying use code:

```
result = driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//comment()[contains(.,'noindex')]")
puts result
```

It returns /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok': invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//comment()[contains(.,'noindex')]" is: [object Comment].

html code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="">
<body class="siteBody">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="headIn">
            <div class="middleBlock">
                <!--noindex-->
                <!--/noindex-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="foot">
    <div class="footerIn">
        <div class="footerBottomLeft">
            <div class="counters">
                <!--/noindex-->
                <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
                <!--/noindex-->
                <!--noindex-->
                <!--LiveInternet counter-->
                <!--/LiveInternet-->
                <!--/noindex-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you share the html code of the part or page

Comment: Please put a minimal example of the HTML into your question. Pointing us to a link isn't a good idea as links break, thereby rendering your question of no use to future people wanting a similar answer. It also wastes the time of those who would help you, by making them go to that link. A lot of them will simply move to another question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution is

result = @driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[comment()[contains(.,'noindex')]]").count